# Paypal integration with Windows forms application

Tags: winforms, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on a Windows forms application and I have to integrate paypal with my application. My application covers paypal direct payment and also one adaptive payment including preapproval. I could do direct payment via api. But my concern is for preapproval process the sender needs to confirm the pre-approval key to authorize the preapproval process. For that we need to redirect to the paypal site so that the sender could log in to the Paypal with his business account and approves the preapporval key. How can i implement this scenario in Windows forms application ? As far as my knowlege with  paypal is concerned, we need to mention the success and cancel url in the request and how could this be implemented with a windows forms application

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in  advance

Boney

Comment: I would love to hear a Feedback, with what kind of solution you ended. Thanks giorgos.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to setup a web service or website that does the processing with PayPal. Setup IPN and have your app show them the PayPal page (either in their browser or via WebBrowser control) and then find a way to authenticate them after purchase. I.e. Find a way to make sure that this person belongs to this entry in your website's DB.

One thing I can think of is that if you host it in the WebBrowser control you could watch the DocumentLoaded event and parse the querystring contents to match its `txn` variable (Transaction ID) with the TXN your site will store in the database.

I'm facing a very similar problem but it's not really safe to do this kind of stuff in Windows Forms apps since they can be easily decompiled, etc.

If you do manage to find a solution, please do share it. I'd love to see how it turns out for you, and it would be good to know for myself since I'm trying to do something very similar.

Comment: I would love to hear a Feedback, with what kind of solution you ended. Thanks giorgos.